# How can I grant access to everyone in domain to send e-mail on behalf of a particular account in Google Apps?

Tags: google-apps-email

We use Google Apps for e-mail and I'd like to grant access for everyone in the domain, including people added in future, to be able to send mail as one particular account.

Is there a way to do this without specifying each account individually, as indicated here?

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=138350

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a [collaborative inbox](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167430?hl=en).

Such an inbox is basically a Google Group, with some special attributes. It can be used to delegate tasks to group members, amongst other things. And it allows group members to send messages on behalf of the group, using the group's email address as the `From:` address.

To create a collaborative inbox, first create a group from your Google Apps control panel (http://www.google.com/a/example.com). On the group members screen, click *Add all users in this domain*:
[image: Screenshot showing the Add all users in this domain button]

Then go to http://groups.google.com, find the group settings, and set it up as a collaborative inbox:
[image: Group settings screenshot]

Messages sent on behalf of the group must be sent from the Google Groups web UI, where you can choose a `From` address:

[image: Screenshot of the New message screen]

Comment: Thanks. I've never seen Collaborative Inbox but it seems directly on point.  Funny thing is, it's been so long since I asked the question I don't remember what I wanted to do in the first place. Glad to have it answered anyways though!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so basically you want to enable all your employs to send e-mails anonymously to each other - using a particular account.

It's no big deal, just e-mail the **Email Address** and **Password** of the email address to all your employees. As simple as that.